# the character variable is not being sorted

Tags: r

```
tablecrt %>%
  pivot_longer(Q1.Op:Q22.Buy, "q", "val") %>%
  mutate(val = factor(val, levels = 9:1 )) %>% 
  tabyl(val, product.or.block, q, show_na = TRUE)
```

the output is being printed in this format

```
Q1.Op    
Q10.JAR    
Q12.Af     
Q21.ex             
Q3.Opi             
Q4.JARaro
```

As, you can see the question are not sort in the correct manner. I would like to have it as

```
Q1.Op             
Q3.Opi            
Q4.JARaro           
Q10.JAR           
Q12.Af
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is sorted correctly. Characters are sorted alphabetically character-wise. "10" is evaluated as "1", then "0", so "Q10" should come before "Q4.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also store it as a factor or just use `vec_order` from below directly:

```
library(stringr)

vec <- c("Q1.Op", "Q10.JAR", "Q12.Af", "Q21.ex", "Q3.Opi", "Q4.JARaro"
vec_order <- names(sort(setNames(as.numeric(str_extract(vec, "\\d+")), vec)))

vec_order
[1] "Q1.Op"     "Q3.Opi"    "Q4.JARaro" "Q10.JAR"   "Q12.Af"    "Q21.ex" 

vec_factor <- factor(vec, vec_order)
```

If you're concerned about readability you should use pipes:

```
library(stringr)

vec %>%
  stringr::str_extract("\\d+") %>% # get one or more digits from your string
  as.numeric() %>% 
  setNames(vec) %>% # named vector: values are numbers, names are original string
  sort() %>% 
  names()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, just wanted to confirm what if the column names are already a part of a dataframe?

Comment: The do `df$vec <- factor(df$vec, vec_factor)` then you can sort it and it will be in the order you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

It is being sorted correctly: it's alphabetically correct. If you want to sort based on integer conversions of arbitrary substrings, then you need to do that, the language is not going to guess that for you.

To sort anything *with* a number *as* a number, perhaps something like:

```r
numrank <- function(z, ...) rank(as.integer(sapply(regmatches(z, gregexpr("\\d+", z)), `[`, 1)), ...)
vec <- c("Q1.Op","Q10.JAR","Q12.Af","Q21.ex","Q3.Opi","Q4.JARaro","QZ")

tibble(v = vec) %>%
  arrange(numrank(v, na.last=FALSE))
# # A tibble: 7 x 1
#   v        
#   <chr>    
# 1 QZ       
# 2 Q1.Op    
# 3 Q3.Opi   
# 4 Q4.JARaro
# 5 Q10.JAR  
# 6 Q12.Af   
# 7 Q21.ex
```

Also supported is `ties.method=...`, see `?rank`.

Quick walk-through on the "code-golfy" function (as @qdread categorized it, I think that that's a fair label). If we `debugonce(numrank)` once and run this, we can break down the different parts.

- First, `gregexpr` is meant to identify and extract patterns from strings; its return is merely a list of vectors of indices (and their "lengths):

  ```r
  z
  # [1] "Q1.Op"     "Q10.JAR"   "Q12.Af"    "Q21.ex"    "Q3.Opi"    "Q4.JARaro" "QZ"       
  str(gregexpr("\\d+", z))
  # List of 7
  #  $ : int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 1
  #   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
  #   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
  #  $ : int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
  #   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
  #  $ : int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
  #   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
  #  $ : int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
  #   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
  #  $ : int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 1
  #   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
  #   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
  #  $ : int 2
  #   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 1
  #   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
  #   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
  #  $ : int -1
  #   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int -1
  #   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
  #   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
  ```

  That's a lot, but note that the first `int 2` means that a matching substring starts at string position 2, and its `"match.length"= int 1` means that that first one is one character long. Jump forward to the end, and see `int -1`, which means that the pattern is not found. This makes sense.
- `regmatches(z, ...)` is used to get the actual substrings from the return from `gregexpr`.

  ```r
  str(regmatches(z, gregexpr("\\d+", z)))
  # List of 7
  #  $ : chr "1"
  #  $ : chr "10"
  #  $ : chr "12"
  #  $ : chr "21"
  #  $ : chr "3"
  #  $ : chr "4"
  #  $ : chr(0)
  ```

  Note (again) that the last one is length-0, this is expected. (If there were multiple pattern-groups in the regex, then each of these list elements may be longer.)
- `` sapply(..., `[`, 1) `` is a trick to extract the first element from each component of the list, and a nice feature is that if the contents of an element are length 0, then this returns `NA`, which is actually desired for our work here. Ultimately, we'd like the return from this to be a `character` *vector* (not `list`), as long as the input.

  ```r
  sapply(regmatches(z, gregexpr("\\d+", z)), `[`, 1)
  # [1] "1"  "10" "12" "21" "3"  "4"  NA
  ```
- `as.integer` should be self-explanatory. (If you have floating-points, then the regex would need to be updated, and this would change to `as.numeric`.)
- The output needs to be able to indicate the relative rank of the elements, so we just pass this vector to `rank`, as well as any other args the user might want. For instance, `na.last=` will push no-number elements to the front (false) or end (true) of the line; and `ties.method=` deals with consecutive same-number elements.

Comment: This solution is great but I think the `numrank` function is a little bit code golfy. It's hard for people to understand what it does if everything is written in one line with 5 nested functions. I would split it up into a few separate statements.

Comment: @qdread, I know what you're saying, and I just don't have the time now. If you want to add notes, that'd be fine, or the OP can go with LMc's recommendation.